# for dentro de otro for siempre que muestra el último resultado

Tags: python, bucle-for, scraping

hola de nuevo amigos,

bueno, sigo atascado con mi proyecto

lo que quiero hacer es analizar una web de partidos de futbol, primero me tengo que conectar a la página donde aparece toda la lista de partidos de ese día, después tengo que entrar en la página de cada partido para buscar la página de análisis y por último tengo que entrar en la página de análisis para scrapear los datos que me interesan

bueno, pues el caso es que siempre me aparece el último resultado, no soy capaz de rellenar la lista con todos los partidos

os pongo el código por si alguno me podéis echar un cable

muchas gracias de antemano

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# lista de partidos del día elegido
url = 'https://es.besoccer.com/livescore/2022-09-17'
matches = requests.get(url)

s_matches = BeautifulSoup(matches.text, 'lxml')

links = s_matches.find('div', attrs={'class':'matches'}).select('a[href*="/partido/"]')
links

link = links[0]
link

link_match = [link.get('href') for link in links]
link_match  # Hasta aquí hemos recibido la lista

# Hacemos un 'for' para que busque analisis en la lista de partidos. 

for url_match in link_match:
        r_analisis = requests.get(url_match)
        if r_analisis.status_code == 200:
            s_analisis = BeautifulSoup(r_analisis.text, 'lxml')
            find_analisis = s_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'menu-scroll'}).select('a[href*="analisis"]')
            analisis = find_analisis[0]
            link_analisis = analisis.get('href')
            #link_analisis = find_analisis.get('href')
            r_link_analisis = requests.get(link_analisis)
            s_link_analisis = BeautifulSoup(r_link_analisis.text, 'lxml') 

            def obtener_stats(s_link_analisis):
                stats_dict = {}
                
                date = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'starttime':'info match-link'})
                if date:
                    stats_dict['date'] = date.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['date'] = None 

                time = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'data'})
                if time:
                    stats_dict['time'] = time.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['time'] = None

                competition = s_link_analisis.find('h3', attrs={'class':'competition'})
                if competition:
                    stats_dict['competition'] = competition.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['competition'] = None

                homeTeam = s_link_analisis.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'homeTeam'})
                if homeTeam:
                    stats_dict['homeTeam'] = homeTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeTeam'] = None

                homeRank = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t1'})
                if homeRank:
                    stats_dict['homeRank'] = homeRank.get_text()
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeRank'] = None    

                homeGoals = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-1'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
                if homeGoals:
                    stats_dict['homeGoals'] = homeGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeGoals'] = None     

                awayTeam = s_link_analisis.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'awayTeam'})
                if awayTeam:
                    stats_dict['awayTeam'] = awayTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayTeam'] = None     

                awayRank = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t2'})
                if awayRank:
                    stats_dict['awayRank'] = awayRank.get_text()
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayRank'] = None     

                awayGoals = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-2'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
                if awayGoals:
                    stats_dict['awayGoals'] = awayGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayGoals'] = None     

                draw = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box draw'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'})
                if draw:
                    stats_dict['draw'] = draw.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['draw'] = None
                
                return stats_dict
            
                df = pd.DataFrame(obtener_stats(s_link_analisis), index=list(range(50)))

                df.head()
           
        else:
            print('1.- No se pudo obtener la página de análisis', url_match)
```

imagen de los que quiero conseguir, pero ahora me aparece siempre el mismo dato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, en Python la indentación es muy importante, no sé si así tienes el código o si fue un error al redactar la pregunta pero tienes dos líneas abajo del `return` que siguen estando adentro de la función. Tal como está el código no hace nada, se tarda mucho y al final no devuelve nada. Por favor revisa que al copiar y pegar haya quedado igual como lo tienes para que podamos reproducir tu problema

Comment: Por otra parte, definir una función adentro de un `for` no es lo mejor, la función se debería definir afuera del `for` y utilizarse en cada iteración.

Comment: Actualización, cambié la indentación de las dos líneas que siguen al `return` y me regresa un montón de datos pero como no pusiste un ejemplo de lo que se espera obtener no sé si son correctos o no. ¿Podrías aclarar cuál es el problema y cuál sería el resultado deseado? Por favor incluye ejemplos, tal vez algunas líneas del `dataframe` que obtienes y unas de como esperarías obtenerlo

Comment: hola @HeytalePazguato, soy muy novato por aquí y programando, así que voy a exprimir al máximo tus conocimientos, jejejejej

Comment: por cierto, no fue ningún error lo de las dos líneas fuera del return, es que realmente no sabía como hacerlo y como no funcionaba he ido probando varias cosas

Comment: con respecto a la función dentro del for, creía que así estaba bien, pero entonces no se cómo debo hacerlo

Comment: he editado la pregunta con una imagen del dataframe para ver si con esto te vale

Comment: No entiendo por que creas una funcion si no la ejecutas en ninguna parte. Pero dejando eso de lado, la razon por la que no conviene crear una funcion dentro de un bucle for es que la estas recreando una y otra vez sin necesidad.

Comment: Otra cosa. Poner un return que siempre  sucedera y luego poner código no tiene sentido. Pues el return es una forma de decir "para la ejecucion de la funcion y devolve este valor". Tldr: el dataframe no se crea. Quiza es un error durante el copiado de codigo, pero te lo aviso ante la duda. Lo digo aunque Heytalepazguato se me haya adelantado.

Comment: Por cierto, lo mas adecuado es usar un objeto encargado de "contener" valores. En este caso te convendria crear un diccionario o lista fuera del for e ir llenandolo de dataframes. Hay muchos tutoriales en internet sobre como usar dichos objetos. Finalmente, retornar el "contenedor".

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, ya voy entendiendo muchas cosas, me he puesto de nuevo a ver más tutoriales. Pero me estáis siendo de mucha ayuda. Muchas gracias